# CallBack Functions in React Native Swift

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, react-native

I'm trying to create a native swift module with a function I can call in my javascript code. Currently I have my `module.swift` file, my `module.m` file, and the bridging header.

Here's MyModule.swift:

```
import Foundation

@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject {

  @objc func callbackMethod(callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
     let resultsDict = [
     "success" : true
     ];

    callback([NSNull() ,resultsDict])
  }

}
```

Here's MyModule.m:

```
import Foundation

@objc(AskPermissions)
class AskPermissions: NSObject {

  @objc func callbackMethod(callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
    let resultsDict = [
     "success" : true
   ];
   print("GLARGH!")
  callback([NSNull() ,resultsDict])
  }

}
```

Here's the bridging header:

```
#import React/RCTBridgeModule.h

#import React/RCTEventEmitter.h
```

Finally, here's my call in javascript:

```
const { MyModule } = require('NativeModules');
MyModule.callbackMethod((err,r) => console.log(r));
```

The problem is that whenever I run the project, it causes an error:

```
Exception 'callbackMethod:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback is not a recognized Objective-c
 method.'
```

However, I can't find anything wrong with the documentation. Could someone please provide some help?

Comment: I'm not that good with native code but is this possible because you are mixing objective-c and swift?

Comment: Try change your "MyModule.m" to
 `#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(callbackMethod:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

@end`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add underscore:
`callbackMethod(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock)`

Comment: What does the underscore do? Can you please explain why that works?